# Overlapping axis labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have an issue where I have overlapping axis labels and can't seem to get a solution to fix this.

[image]

```
p <- ggplot(data=Data,aes(x=Indicator,y=Numeric,group=Expenditure_group,shape=Expenditure_group,colour=Expenditure_group))+geom_point()+geom_line()
```

Is there a way to fix this so that there are no overlaps?

Comment: This has now been fixed in the latest version of ggplot2 (ver 3.3.0). Can do, for example p + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can tune a bit your x axis either by automatically abbreviating labels as in

```
p + scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)
```

or you can provide abbreviated labels yourself as in

```
p + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Congenital Rubella" = "C. Rub.", ..., "Total tetanus" = "T. tet.", "Yellow fever" = "Y. fever")
```

See: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_discrete.html

Comment: This is a good answer, but another personal favorite is to alternate a newline character at the beginning of every xlabel:
`p + scale_x_discrete( labels = function( labels ) {
            fixedLabels <- c()
            for ( l in 1:length( labels ) )
            {
                fixedLabels <- c( fixedLabels,
                    paste0( ifelse( l %% 2 == 0,
                        '', '\n' ), labels[l] ) )
            }
            return( fixedLabels )
        } )`