# How to alternate a new line for overlapping x axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting long text factors in the x axis ggplot does not make a very good job. I want to alternate a new line so it is more legible (so the red marks labels in the picture below should be a line down).

I've found an answer to this in the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567986/overlapping-axis-labels-in-r) but can't make work. The code is:

```
scale_x_discrete( labels = function( labels ) { 
fixedLabels <- c() for ( l in 1:length( labels ) ) { 
fixedLabels <- c( fixedLabels, paste0( ifelse( l %% 2 == 0, '', '\n' ), labels[l] ) ) } return( fixedLabels ) } )
```

Test data:

```
library(ggplot2)

Group = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14")
x = c(141, 57, 38, 18, 13, 7, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

dat <- data.frame(
  Group = Group,
  x = x,
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)

dat <- dat[order(dat$x, decreasing=TRUE), ]
dat$Group <- factor(dat$Group, levels=dat$Group[order(dat$x, decreasing=TRUE)])
cum = sum(dat$x)
dat$cum <- 100*(dat$x)/cum
dat$cum = cumsum(dat$cum)

> dat
   Group   x       cum
1     D1 141  48.45361
2     D2  57  68.04124
3     D3  38  81.09966
4     D4  18  87.28522
5     D5  13  91.75258
6     D6   7  94.15808
7     D7   5  95.87629
8     D8   4  97.25086
9     D9   2  97.93814
10   D10   2  98.62543
11   D11   1  98.96907
12   D12   1  99.31271
13   D13   1  99.65636
14   D14   1 100.00000

 ggplot(dat, aes(x=Group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=x), fill="light blue", stat="identity") +
  stat_count(aes(label = x), geom = "text", vjust=-0.3, size=3.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=cum)) +
  geom_path(aes(y=cum, group=1))
```

[image: Pareto Chart]

Comment: Rotating the plot by 90 degrees is another way to deal with long axis labels. With ggplot2, you would add `+ coord_flip()` to rotate the plot. The `ggstance` package also has geoms for horizontal plots (e.g., `geom_barh`). If you want value labels, you could place them below zero so that the labels don't interfere with the visual mapping of bar height to magnitude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a neat little trick you found in the comments! It does work, just make sure you watch your syntax: `l` != `1` although it looks *very* similar:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = x), fill = "light blue", stat = "identity") +
  stat_count(aes(label = x), geom = "text", vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = cum)) +
  geom_path(aes(y = cum, group = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(labels) {
    fixedLabels <- c()
    for (l in 1:length(labels)) {
      fixedLabels[l] <- paste0(ifelse(l %% 2 == 0, '', '\n'), labels[l])
    }
    return(fixedLabels)
  })
```

[image: Plot]

Note: You could choose to rewrite the syntax more succinctly (here I'm using `i` to avoid confusion and maybe make it more readable):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = x), fill = "light blue", stat = "identity") +
  stat_count(aes(label = x), geom = "text", vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = cum)) +
  geom_path(aes(y = cum, group = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(labels) {
    sapply(seq_along(labels), function(i) paste0(ifelse(i %% 2 == 0, '', '\n'), labels[i]))
  })
```

Comment: That worked perfect. Sorry for the late accepted, you know, friday :P

Answer (score 12):

From `ggplot2` 3.3.2 onwards, you can simply use `scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))`. This is discussed in the [release notes](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/).

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = manufacturer)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It´s amazing how often i come back here again. Very useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not what you were asking, but another nice way to handle long axis labels is to place them at a 45* angle:

```
Group = c("LongerNameD1", "LongerNameD2", "LongerNameD3", "LongerNameD4", "LongerNameD5", "LongerNameD6", "LongerNameD7", "LongerNameD8", "LongerNameD9", "LongerNameD10", "LongerNameD11", "LongerNameD12", "LongerNameD13", "LongerNameD14")
x = c(141, 57, 38, 18, 13, 7, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

dat <- data.frame(
     Group = Group,
     x = x,
     stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)

dat <- dat[order(dat$x, decreasing=TRUE), ]
dat$Group <- factor(dat$Group, levels=dat$Group[order(dat$x, decreasing=TRUE)])
cum = sum(dat$x)
dat$cum <- 100*(dat$x)/cum
dat$cum = cumsum(dat$cum)


ggplot(dat, aes(x = Group)) +
     geom_bar(aes(y = x), fill = "light blue", stat = "identity") +
     stat_count(aes(label = x), geom = "text", vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) + 
     geom_point(aes(y = cum)) +
     geom_path(aes(y = cum, group = 1))+
     theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, I'll try that, looks awesome!